# C# WPF fix Grid in Scrollviewer only in one direction

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, grid, scrollviewer

I have a XAML Page where I have 4 Grids (rectGrid, dateGrid, roomGrid, optionGrid)  , 3 of them (rectGrid, dateGrid, roomGrid) are created dynamically (in Code Behind)

What i want to do is that the rectGrid is scrollable Horizontal and Vertical, but the roomGrid only Horizontal and the dateGrid only vertical

**Here's the Code**

```
 <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

    <Grid>

        <Grid Name="optionsGrid">
            <Label Name="lZeit" Content="Zeitraum:  von" Margin="100,7,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
            <DatePicker Name="dpVon" Margin="192,7,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="23"></DatePicker>
            <Label Name="lBis" Content="bis" Margin="372,7,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
            <DatePicker Name="dpBis" Margin="440,8,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="23"></DatePicker>
            <Button Content="OK" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="620,6,0,0" Name="selectDates" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" RenderTransformOrigin="-2.552,0.522" Click="selectDates_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Drucken" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="740,6,0,0" Name="print" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" RenderTransformOrigin="-2.552,0.522" Click="print_Click"/>
        </Grid>



        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="100,70" Name="rectGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" OpacityMask="Black" Opacity="1" ShowGridLines="False" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        </Grid>

        <Grid Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="98,31,0,0" Name="dateGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="656*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1129*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Width="82" Name="roomGrid" Margin="0,70">
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</ScrollViewer>
```

**Here's a Screenshot:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMbAY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the `Grids` in a `ScrollViewer`, do this;

`<Grid Name="optionsGrid" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">`

OR

`<Grid Name="optionsGrid" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">`

I don't really understand your question or the naming of the `Grids` so you will need to change that as you see fit.

Comment: I will try this thanks!

For describing you my Grids: I'm programming a CalenderView for a hotel where he can click on a rectangle(rectGrid) and then a dialog appears where he can book a room! At the top there are DateLabels(DateGrid) and on the Left the roomGrid with Labels which contains the name of the room! Every room has one rectangle for every Date which is Displayed!

(i added a ScreenShot do my question!

Comment: When i try it like you, no ScrollViewer appears :(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

```
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="rectGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" OpacityMask="Black" Opacity="1" ShowGridLines="False" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```